# Whether Cucumber JUnit can be used to UnitTest Spring?

Tags: java

Whether Cucumber JUnit along with Mockito can be used to test Spring? Wherever I see it's either only using Mockito JUnit or SpringJUnit Runner and have never seen UnitTestCases with Cucumber JUnit+Mockito for Spring..

Whether that is really possible?

Answer (score 0):

The problems those technologies aim to solve is very different.

In an unit test you are trying to test the smallest possible piece of your software (normally a single class) and you abstract (mock) everything else. This is a very good use case for Mockito.

JUnit runner and SpringTestRunner are the engines running your tests, they will take care of configuration and class loading for you.

Cucumber allows you to write tests in a language that is more business friendly (Gherkin) and your goal here is to cover business user cases and test your entire application to see if it solves your problems.

For example: lets say you have an application that gives you the tax value to be added to a check.

You can have a class that given a product connects to an external service and returns the tax rate for that item. To test that class you don't hit the real service, you use Mockito to create a mock service where you can control the returned values. Here you are testing the ability of your class to make requests to external services.

Now you can have a business requirement that says that if you have multiple items in your check only some of them are taxed. Here you write a cucumber test and send the request to your application. Here you are testing the full logic of your app, recognizing items, getting taxes for the right ones and so on.

Thats a case where you will have cucumber and Mockito running on the same app. And who is running them? Most likely the JUnit runner.

Comment: But we are trying to use Cucumber for also even smallest piece of the software so that in future any Developer would be able to understand it..

Comment: Can you post an example? Cucumber could not be the right tool for that job.